# Как передать список из одного класса в другой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, tkinter

В виджете `Label` класса `Text` необходимо указать принадлежность к фрейму, который создается в класса `Frames`, значение, а точнее список фреймов, с параметрами, сохраняются в список `self.List_frames`, требуется передать этот список в класс `Text`, а затем указать в виджете `Label` принадлежность к одному из фреймов в списке, обратившись к нему по индексу, как лучше всего это реализовать?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


root = Tk()
root.title('Python')
root.geometry('605x400')
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)


# Класс реализации фреймов
class Frames():
    # Инициализация заданых параметров
    def __init__(self, background_line, width_line, height_line):
        self.background_line = background_line
        self.width_line = width_line
        self.height_line = height_line
        # Лист фреймов 
        self.List_frames = []
        # Лист имен фреймов 
        self.List_name_frames = ['One_line', 'Two_line', 'Three_line', 'Four_line', \
                                 'Five_line', 'Six_line', 'Seven_line', 'Eight_line',\
                                 'Nine_line', 'Ten_line']
        
        # Создание фреймов, присвоение параметров к фреймам, запись фреймов в список
        for name_line in self.List_name_frames:
            name_line = Frame(root, background = self.background_line, \
                              width = self.width_line, height = self.height_line)
            self.List_frames.append(name_line)
        
        # Вызов созданных фреймов с параметрами на экран
        for line in self.List_frames:
            line.pack(anchor = W)
            line.pack_propagate(False)
  
    

# Класс реализации текста
class Text():
    def __init__(self, text, background_text, font_text, foreground_text, width_texts):
        self.Pixel_Virtual = tk.PhotoImage(width = 1)
        self.text = text
        self.background_text = background_text
        self.font_text = font_text
        self.foreground_text = foreground_text
        self.width_text = width_texts
        
        # Создание текстового поля [День:]
        Day = Label(image = self.Pixel_Virtual, text = self.text,
                    background = self.background_text, font = self.font_text,
                    foreground = self.foreground_text, width = self.width_text)
        

# Создаем обьект класса фреймов
# Параметры: цвет фона, ширина, высота
call_Frames = Frames('olivedrab', 605, 40)

# Создаем обьект класса текста
# Параметры: текст, цвет фона, стиль текста, цвет текста, ширина блока с текстом
call_Text = Text('День', 'green', 'Arial 12', 'black', 40) 

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, нужно использовать переменную класса вместо переменной экземпляра

```
# Класс реализации фреймов
class Frames():
    # Лист фреймов 
    List_frames = []
    # Инициализация заданых параметров
    def __init__(self, background_line, width_line, height_line):
        self.background_line = background_line
        self.width_line = width_line
        self.height_line = height_line
```

```
# Функция текстового поля [День:]
    def day(self):
        Day = Label(Frames.List_frames[0], image = self.Pixel_Virtual, text = self.text,
                    background = self.background_text, font = self.font_text,
                    foreground = self.foreground_text, width = self.width_text,
                    height = self.height_texts)
        Day.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 2, pady = 2)
```